# While launching the react native application getting exception

Tags: react-native

I am not able to find where I did wrong

It is happening when I am running the Metro bundler

```
BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1491/1491), done.

 LOG  Running "Trepr" with {"rootTag":1}
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at render (http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:183726:35)
    at finishClassComponent (http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:17810:43)
```

Comment: problem with 'length' you must have used length with string or array in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to get property `legnth` of the `null` array.
so you need to code like this..

```
array !== null && array !== undefined && array.length
```